# class a{..}; typedef a a_t; union u{...; a_t ai;...}; doesn't work

Tags: c++

I wrote a class for a fixed point number, class q1516 {...}, with a lot of overloading stuff. It seems to work pretty well. q1516_t shall be as far as possible like a basic data type (like the complex numbers etc.).
The class has as its only data field a 32-bit unsigned word.
I also defined a type: typedef q1516 q1516_t; and I could use it as expected (I have learned that this doesn't call a constructor ans shall adjust the test cases).
At least I got no compiler messages and the tests passed.

Now I want to define a union as part of a return value:

```
typedef union uTelemetryDataValue {
    float       f;
    q1516_t     q;
} tdValue_t;
```

but it doesn't work, the message is:
'q1516_t' does not name a type.
The header files are included in the correct order: "q1516.h" before the header which contains the above declaration of uTelemetryDataValue.

How can I do it better?
I have read 15501649/c-typedef-class-use: Ok, typedef is old C, but what should be put into uTelemetryDataValue?
My main aim (besides clean *and simple* C++ ) is to allow the choice, that a returned structure contains a float or a fixed point number (which of these is specified elsewhere).

(Eclipse-cdt, Mingw, Win8.1, but final target will be an embedded device)

Thank you very much in advance,
Helmut

Comment: Please give us real code: minimal example that we can try to compile.

Comment: In C++, there is absolutely no need to `typedef` your `struct`s and `union`s.

Comment: You likely have circular includes

Comment: Or a namespace problem?

Comment: Where is the type "q1516_t" declared/defined?

Comment: "I have learned that this doesn't call a constructor". Dubious and unclear.

Comment: `typedef` doesn't define a type, it defines an alias for an existing type

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments, I checked them as thoroughly as I can.

@n.m. In thread 15501649 I read:
"...It provides no notational benefits in C++ as it does in C. OTOH, it leads to restrictions because this syntax does not provide any mechanism for construction, or destruction."
and I interpreted it such that no constructor is invoked. But this is not the center of the question.
@HolyBlackCat: I wanted to spare you reading all this, my question wasn't for debugging but for doing it "correctly". But: Thank you for the offer.
@5gon12eder: I'm sure you're right. I asked for the "correct way" not to use typedefs.
I received help also elsewhere and together with the comments of Dieter, Dan and John we got some answers.

Dieter, no circular includes but still wrong order (:-}), sorry. These are now the first lines of the to be written module MLinkDrv.cpp (it is quite empty yet):

```
#include <stdint.h> // uint32_t etc.
#include "../q1516/q1516.h" // contains the class definition for q15161
#include "TelemetryData.h" // contains the union declaration for uTelemetryDataValue
#include "MLinkDrv.h" // uses declarations in q1516.h and TelemetryData.h
using namespace std;
```

Sorry, I oversaw that the order was still wrong when I wrote the question:
MLinkDrv.h, then
q1516.h and then
TelemetryData.h.
**But** the compiler message was delivered in TelemetryData.h, **not** in MLinkDrv.h as to be expected and so I oversaw the fault. This is my only excuse...

After reordering the quality of the error messages improved: The compiler could not put q1516 (or q15161_t) into the union because the class q1516 has a nontrivial copy constructor. A bit better.
After adjusting the class q1516 I got a new surprise:
In *C/C++ Build* | *settings* | *Tool settings* I had to add " -std=c++11",
obviously such a simple thing like putting a float and a class (with one uint32_t in its data) into a union needs C++11.

So the question is possibly not answered explicitely:
How is a construct like the following formulated in "good C++", and I add: without using C++11 if possible:

```
class cTDItem {
private:
    tdInfo_t    id; //...
    tdValue_t   value;
    uint32_t    timestamp;
...
}
```

The id contains information, among other, of which type the value is. It is a simple struct and I do use typedef here.
The value is the union:

```
typedef union uTelemetryDataValue {
    float       f;
    q1516_t     q;
} tdValue_t;
```

1st Answer: Ok, I can/should write the class name q1516 insted of the type q1516_t. More?

Thank you for your help so far and have fine Christmas Hollydays!

Helmut